# Table padding on print with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to dynamically generate an HTML document using vanilla Javascript. I have a large table that would take about 4 pages on an A4 sheet. The table overflows onto the next page with the table header being added to the start of each new page.
I've horizontally padded it by placing the table within a container to provide some safe space while printing.

Can I do the same for vertical padding using vanilla Javascript to add some safe space to the top of each page that the table overflows into, without having to split it up into a new table and applying the required styling property to every table on every page.

Comment: Maybe something [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/), but it's CSS.

Comment: Yes you can. And you most likely have to inject CSS via JS but we can't really help further since there is no code to talk about

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.